# improve performance of uploading data to database

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

I have a c# application. When it runs it calculates about 50,000 to 100,000 values. I then store these values into a sql server database. The code below works fine however it takes a very long time to upload the data to the database. I would like to know if there is anything I can do to improve the performance? It currently take over a minute.

My Sql table shown below. Should I be using a primary key here as I imagine this must take extra processing time when inserting the data?

```
 tblResultEquityCurve

 DTime (smalldatetime) - primary key
 Equity numeric(18,4)
```

**C# code**

```
void exEquityCurveMT()
        {
            DeletePreviousResultsFromTable("Result_EquityCurve");

            Spliter[] split = MTSplitter(Account.EquityHistory.Count);
            MultiThreadToDataBase[] mtDB = new MultiThreadToDataBase[NUMCORES];

            Task[] taskDB = new Task[NUMCORES];
            for (int i = 0; i < taskDB.Length; i++)
            {
                List<structEquity> eqyList = Account.EquityHistory.GetRange((int)split[i].rowStart, split[i].numRows);
                mtDB[i] = new MultiThreadToDataBase();
                taskDB[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(mtDB[i].exEquityCurve, eqyList);
            }
            try
            {
                Task.WaitAll(taskDB);
            }
            catch (AggregateException ex)
            {
                ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(ex.InnerException).Throw();
            }

        }




public void exEquityCurve(object dataObj)
        {
            List<structEquity> dataList = (List<structEquity>)dataObj;

            using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();

                using (SqlCommand commandEquity = new SqlCommand("dbo.InsertEquityCurve", connection))
                {
                    commandEquity.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    commandEquity.Parameters.Add("@dtTime", System.Data.SqlDbType.SmallDateTime);
                    commandEquity.Parameters.Add("@Equity", System.Data.SqlDbType.Float);

                    for (int i = 0; i < dataList.Count; i++)
                    {
                        commandEquity.Parameters["@dtTime"].Value = dataList[i].dTime;
                        commandEquity.Parameters["@Equity"].Value = dataList[i].Equity;
                        commandEquity.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }                                
                }

                connection.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: If your upload is just a simple row-by-row inserts, you might want to look into [SqlBulkCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: thanks very much! SqlBulkCopy makes it so much quicker

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not a good practice to call a DB stored procedure from a loop. Either use [SqlBulkCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx) as suggested by [Jamez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4420967/jamesz), or create another stored procedure that would accept a table valued parameter via user defined table type, see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx). User defined types in MSSQL have known maintainability issues, so you could use XML instead, although it does make you sproc contract and signature less declarative.
Either way the goal is to pass all data in one async call to the database.